# Reading endmember from each scene in image collection of Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to do spectral unmixing over a Landsat 8 image collection. I want to take endmember values from a particular location in each scene, but I keep getting this error (I have already followed the debugging guide for this error)

```js
 List (Error)
 Failed to decode JSON.
 Error: Field 'value' of object '{"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}' is 
 missing or null.
 Object: {"type":"ArgumentRef","value":null}.
```

When I use the inspector to click on the polygons I am using to define my endmembers, there are just zero values (which explains the error message). 
The exact same code works when I'm running the code over a single image rather than an image collection.

Here is what I'm working with: SEE CODE HERE https://code.earthengine.google.com/d82288e11c364b3037fdbca5e185c116

I load my landsat collection with a cloud filter, then run this code:

```js
 var sma_unmixL8 = (function(image) {
   var s_image= image.select("B2","B3","B4","B5","B6", "B7");

   //endmembers collected from each image scene.

   var veg = s_image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry:veg_em, scale: 30, maxPixels: 1e8});
   var vegvalues = veg.values();
   print (vegvalues, 'vegvalues')

   var water= s_image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry:water_em, scale: 30, maxPixels: 1e8});
   var watervalues = water.values();
   print(watervalues, 'watervalues')

   var soil= s_image.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry:soil_em, scale: 30, maxPixels: 1e8});
   var soilvalues = soil.values();
   print(soilvalues, 'soilvalues')

   //constrained to one no neg code
  var unmixed_a = s_image.unmix([watervalues, vegvalues, soilvalues],true,true);
  var unmixed =  unmixed_a.multiply(900);

   return unmixed;
   });
```

The error appears for each endmember when I try to print.
When I run the entire code with a single set of endmember values gathered from a single scene, it runs OK.

Any ideas?

Comment: edit: This error persists even after removing the printing. It will run and not display errors, but when I get to downloading the output it gives me an error saying " Image.unmix: Element 0 of list 'endmembers[1]' must not be null."

Comment: For debugging it would be helpfull if you share the full code and all necessary Assets (geometries, fusion tables, etc.).

Comment: Oh, okay! I have edited the question thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to map that function over an `ImageCollection`, then the `print()` statements in there won't work.  See [the debugging doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#server-side-errors) and/or [the client-server doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) to understand why.

Comment: Thanks - when i comment out the print statements though, the endmembers are still null, the error appears later when I try to export table to drive.

Comment: No way to know why without knowing more about the geometries and images.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out how to link the whole code https://code.earthengine.google.com/d82288e11c364b3037fdbca5e185c116